# RTK Query code generation - can we generate short model names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using the documentation here to generate some RTK Query api files/models, using a SWAGGER openApi json file.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-generation

This is all working great, other than one annoyance of the model names being generated with ridiculously long names.  When using these in my components it is looking messy and hard to read as there is always a load of extra text at the front before I get to the model name.

E.g. as an example it is producing the interface names like this:

`MyCompanyServiceMyServiceNameWebModelsActualModelNameModel`

I understand this will be done to try and minimise conflicts, but I was wondering if there is a way to override this behaviour to give shorter names?

E.g. the model name I actually want from the above example is `ActualModelName`